# c++ Run code while asleep

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

So I'm a beginner making text based tetris and I'd like that the piece goes down every 150ms or so but u'd be able to move the pieces left and right while that is running.

Sleep obviously doesn't work so any alternatives?

```
while (true) {
    draw();

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT]) {
    leftright(1);
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) {
    leftright(-1);

}

    check();
    move(1);

    check();

    checkline();
    movedown();

    Sleep(x);
    system("CLS");
}
```

Comment: Use/create a timer?

Comment: You need a GUI with an event loop, so that a timer event can tell you when to move the piece or a keyboard event can tell you when the user is moving.

Comment: So what kind of timer are we talking about? How can i count time without sleeping a millisecond? Or should I divide the 150ms to smaller ones and do code between these?

Comment: This is a really broad topic, far too much so for a Q&A posting. You should read a book about program design and how to create games!

Comment: You can check more frequently and sleep for a shorter duration.  Usually this would be done in the draw loop.

Comment: @Toqoz: This is neither usual nor advisable. Sleeping has generally lower accuracy than its precision suggests. This isn't going to be a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is to use a timer. I understand the movedown() function in your code handles pulling the pieces down. Make it so that it only does so if enough time has passed since last call. Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
static std::clock_t start = std::clock(); // take the start ticks at the beginning

int movedown() {

    std::clock_t currentTime = std::clock();
    double duration = (start - currentTime) * 1000/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // multiplied by thousand to get time in ms

    if ((long int) duration > 150)
    {
    **/* Your algorithm here */**
    start = std::clock(); //update start
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Personally I would find it more intuitive if the movedown function did what it said it does. I'd move the  check for whether you should move down outside the function. e.g. `if(duration > 150) movedown()`